# Can't update Visual Studio Installer (no error message)

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to install the latest version of Visual Studio Community 2017, however I'm having a few issues. I downloaded the Visual Studio installer and run it. After trying to go through it, it just shows and empty dialog box with the only option being to close. There's no error or anything, but if I'm not wrong, it should open the window showing which parts of Visual Studio I want to install. Screenshots showing the process:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Anyone have any experience with this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: No, and it's only a few months ago since I actually installed Visual Studio 2017 for the first time on this computer, and nothing major should be different from back then when it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the steps as below to completely remove the VS 2017:

1. Go to Control Panel—Programs and Features, right click the ‘Microsoft Visual Studio 2017’ and choose ‘Uninstall’
2. Try to delete the following installed folders: %ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages and %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community

After that, make sure windows update is up-to-date, clean up the %temp% folder, temporarily disable any antivirus, download the latest installer from [Visual Studio Downloads](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) and run it as administrator to install.

If this issue persists, please use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs and find vslogs.zip under the %temp% folder, then upload the file to [Onedrive](https://onedrive.live.com) and share the link here.

Comment: I did what you asked, deleted Visual Studio and deleted the program data and the temp folder, it still doesn't work. I uploaded the vslogs.zip file here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AueEA7nx5mnchWOm8PN_vgQEUmsb

Comment: Actually, I got it work. Turns out there were still updates for Windows to be installed, which fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, we have fix this in the next major Visual Studio update release.  (15.4)

The WMI service on your machine was not working (due to pending OS update).  The Bootstrapper depends on WMI service and since WMI service is not working correctly, ManagementException is thrown.  In 15.4, we have removed the Bootstrapper's dependency on WMI.

If you see this error again, you can try the followings to workaround this issue.

Workaround:
1. Download latest Bootstrapper from https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/ and run vs_enterprise.exe --passive --update in an admin command console window. (this will force update your VS Installer)

OR

2. Reboot your machine and follow this instruction to repair WMI: 
   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-us/8ed26d46-9994-4052-a307-5b071805aea8/wmi-corrupt-how-to-reinstallrepair?forum=winservergen

OR

3. Make sure your OS is up to date.

thanks for reporting this issue.
toby.